# What is the correct distance of "Al Kauther "?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, hadith-interpretation, jannah

According to Sahih Hadeeth "Al Kauther" has different distances. Which one is the correct distance?

> **Volume 8, Book 76, Number 579**:  Narrated Ibn 'Umar:  The Prophet said,
>   "There will be a tank (Lake-Fount) in front of you as large as the
>   distance  between **Jarba** and **Adhruh** (two towns in Sham)."
>
> Volume 8, Book 76, Number 582:  Narrated Anas bin Malik:  Allah's
>   Apostle said, "The width of my Lake-Fount is equal to the distance
>   between **Aila** (a town in  Sham) and **Sana**' (the capital of Yemen) and it
>   has as many (numerous) jugs as the number of stars of the sky."
>
> Volume 8, Book 76, Number 591:  Narrated Haritha bin Wahb:  I heard
>   the Prophet mentioning the Lake-Fount (Al-Kauthar), saying, "(The
>   width of the Lake-  Fount) is equal to the distance between **Medina** and
>   **Sana'** (capital of Yemen)." Haritha said that he  heard the Prophet
>   saying that his Lake-Fount would be as large as the distance between
>   Sana' and  Medina. Al-Mustaurid said to Haritha, "Didn't you hear him
>   talking about the vessels?" He said, "No."  Al-Mustaurid said, "The
>   vessels are seen in it as (numberless as) the stars."

Which is the most authentic understanding of this distance?

Comment: Your question about whether all these hadith should be considered sahih was mostly tangential to the *actual* question about the distance of al-Kauthar. I have posted that as a separate question here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35221/22

Comment: @goldPseudo these hadiths might only be an expression, for instance in the Quran: 9:80 "Ask forgiveness for them, [O Muhammad], or do not ask forgiveness for them. If you should ask forgiveness for them seventy times - never will Allah forgive them. That is because they disbelieved in Allah and His Messenger, and Allah does not guide the defiantly disobedient people."

The number 70 isn't what matters. Even if he would ask forgivness for them 1000 times. As it says in "Ask forgiveness for them, [O Muhammad], or do not ask forgiveness for them." i.e it doesn't matter how much you ask!